# Offline non-browser-based bookmark manager for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bookmark

I am looking for a bookmark manager that can help me store URL links. Requirements:

- It should store at least the following fields: title, URL, tags, description, date added.
- It should also be completely offline, and run completely on the desktop (either GUI, command line, or both). It must not run in a browser (i.e. no browser plugins).
- It must be able to import existing bookmarks from web browsers without loss of information (including the preservation of the date the bookmark was added to the browser)<sup>†</sup>
- It must be able to export bookmarks for import into web browsers.
- It must run on Ubuntu.

---

<sup>†</sup> To my knowledge, the "[buku](https://github.com/jarun/buku)" bookmark manager fails this requirement. It does not preserve the initial add date. Imports are lossy. Refer to issue [#304](https://github.com/jarun/buku/issues/304) (closed, wontfix) on buku's issue tracker.

Comment: Flux/ how did this work out for you?  I'm looking at `buku` and wasn't aware that it didn't keep the date.  That seems ... well, not really sensible.  Did you find another solution?

Comment: @Diagon I have not found a solution. You could open a new ticket on GitHub and link to the two previous issues: [#304](https://github.com/jarun/buku/issues/304) and [#477](https://github.com/jarun/buku/issues/477). Try to convince the maintainer to keep information that is kept by the built-in bookmark managers in web browsers.

Comment: Flux/ I read them.  He's not going to do it.  Look, I'm not much with coding: I don't know more than a smattering of git and I don't do much more than bash and C, but if there were some way we could cooperate on adding one more column to the DB, I'd be up for trying.  It might not be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from buku, another one to explore is [wallabag](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag).

But I can't confirm if offline has now been now resolved. See old [issue](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag/issues/1084)